# Using FileSystemWatcher with files having FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS

Tags: c#, onedrive, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to use the FileSystemWatcher class in C# to detect changes made on files. The folder I am using is the OneDrive for Business local folder (e.g. C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - COMPANY\MySubfolder)

The problem is that inside this folder there are files that may not be fully synchronized (using the Windows explorer you will see the cloud icon in blue) and FileSystemWatcher does not see these files.

Is there any way to include these files? If I use the Directory.GetFiles method, C# can well see these files.

Thanks.

Comment: FSW sees local changes, not files. Are you saying that eg `Directory.GetFiles()` doesn't return those files? Or that changes made to a remote file don't surface as *local* changes in the local folder? `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS` means that the file will be downloaded when needed. When that happens, the FSW *should* raise Created and Changed events.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-works